# wanna to read hdf file in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, hdf5, stat, hdf

gss = pd.read_hdf('gss.hdf5', 'gs')
this the code i have used on VS code. and i got this

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\pthon_txt\t.py", line 4, in <module>
    gss = pd.read_hdf('gss.hdf5', 'gs')
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Mohammed\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pandas\io\pytables.py", line 442, in read_hdf
    return store.select(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Mohammed\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pandas\io\pytables.py", line 847, in select
    raise KeyError(f"No object named {key} in the file")
KeyError: 'No object named gs in the file'
PS D:\pthon_txt>
```

i wanna to load this hdf file in pandas data  frame

Comment: Have you tried using `pd.read_hdf('gss.hdf5')` alone? The error complains that `gs` doesn't exist in the file

Comment: I had just tried it, and it's worked successfully

Comment: I have one more question, if anyone knows to build a Cdf function to compare the distribution

Comment: Post a new question then. StackOverflow is a Q&A site, not a discussion forum. Comments only appear to other people that have already commented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is saying that the key `gs` doesn't exist in the file. If there's only one key you can use `read_hdf` without the key parameter, eg :

```
df = pd.read_hdf('gss.hdf5')
```

Answer (score 2):

To know which keys stored in your HDF store, use the following code:

```
with pd.HDFStore('gss.hdf5') as store:
    print(store.keys())
```

After that, you will be able to load your data with the correct key:

```
gss = pd.read_hdf('gss.hdf5', <KEY>)
```